# Error in Facebook SDK iOS. FBSDKLog: An existing state change handler was assigned to the session and will be overwritten

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to make a function that login and logout the user when i click on the segmented button in the settings of my app. when the user clicks on Yes and the user is not yet login to Facebook, I'm opening a session and make the user login using safari, and when the user clicks on the No button, i want the app to logout the user and re-enter its email and password when the Yes button is clicked again.

[image]

and the code is this:

```
- (IBAction)fbSegmentTapped:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex)
{
    case 0:{
        if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
            //Session is active
            NSLog(@"Active 1");
            if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:FB_TOKEN] !=nil) {
                [self sendPostRequestToAPI_Yes];
            }else{
                NSLog(@"FB Token null");
            }
        } else {
            // try to open session with existing valid token
            NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                    @"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends",
                                    nil];
            FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permissions];
            [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
            if([FBSession openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI:NO]) {
                //Session is active
                NSLog(@"Active 2");
                if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:FB_TOKEN] !=nil) {
                    NSLog(@"Move to Yes function");
                    [self sendPostRequestToAPI_Yes];
                }else{
                    NSLog(@"You nid to login the user");
                    [self userLogin];
                }
            } else {
                // you need to log the user
                [self userLogin];
                dataClass.fb_flag = @"false";
                NSLog(@"user must login first");
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    case 1:{
        //No
        NSLog(@"Clear the token and remove the session");
        [self sendPostRequestToAPI_No];
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
}
}
```

this function is when the user clicks no

```
-(void) sendPostRequestToAPI_No{
NSDictionary * dict2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: FB_PROVIDER, [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"id"], nil]
                                                   forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name",@"user_id", nil]];

[webServiceController postRequestFromUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", ROOT_SERVER_URL, FB_SETTINGS_NO_URL] withDictionary:dict2];
}
```

and this is for Yes

```
-(void) sendPostRequestToAPI_Yes{
NSLog(@"%@ - %@ - %@ - %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:FB_EMAIL], [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:FB_PROVIDER_ID], [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:FB_TOKEN], [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:SESSION_TOKEN]);

NSLog(@"Provider ID: %@ and Email: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"id"], [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:FB_USER_DETAILS] valueForKey:@"email"]);

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:FB_TOKEN]!=nil) {[self userLogin];}
else{
    NSDictionary * dict2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                                FB_PROVIDER,
                                                                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:FB_EMAIL],
                                                                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:FB_PROVIDER_ID],
                                                                PUBLIC_KEY,
                                                                SECRET_KEY,
                                                                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:FB_TOKEN],
                                                                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:SESSION_TOKEN],
                                                                nil]
                                                       forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name",@"email",@"provider_id", @"public_key", @"secret_key",@"token",@"session_token", nil]];

    [webServiceController postRequestFromUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", ROOT_SERVER_URL, FB_SETTINGS_YES_URL] withDictionary:dict2];
}
}
```

What could be the error?. it always returns: FBSDKLog: An existing state change handler was assigned to the session and will be overwritten.

Comment: Have you got the solution for this?

Comment: didn't find good solutions yet. but i think the problem is on the auth. Because we are also implemented twitter on our app. What we do is redo